# Set environment variable automatically upon SSH login (no root access)

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, environment-variables, login

The situation:

I run Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on a virtual machine.

I regularly have to connect to my account on a university server, I do this by opening up terminal and using `ssh -Y username@server.com`.

Once there I always have to run the following

`setenv PYTHONPATH "place/stuff/this_goes_on_forever"`

And also a few other lines of code.

What I want:

1. My main request: I would like to prepare a script and have that run automatically whenever I log in to the server via ssh.
2. This is a side query, but when I use `alias p="pwd"` (for example) the new aliases do not 'take', typing `p` in this case results in 'command not found'. Is this just a consequence of not being root, or because I am logged in via ssh, or is there a fix for this perhaps?

Attempts at a solution:

I tried adding `export PYTHONPATH="..."` to my local `~/.bashrc` file which means when I start terminal `PYTHONPATH` is set, however after I `ssh` to the server it is no longer set (well I have a whole new host of environment variables). I tried `~/.bash_profile` after, didn't work.

I have tried adding `export PYTHONPATH="..."` to the `~/.bash_profile` file on the server, and also to the `~/.bashrc` file- but neither worked.

I do not have root access on the server so cannot change `AcceptEnv` or `PermitUserEnvironement` within the `sshd_config` file on the server, it is just read-only.

Surely there is somewhere I can put this code, I just can't find where.

Comment: What shell do you run on the remote server? Connect to the server and run `echo $0`.

Comment: `echo $0` returns `-tcsh`

Comment: OK, then see my answer. You should add `setenv PYTHONPATH "place/stuff/this_goes_on_forever"` to `~/.tcshrc` on the remote server. You can also use `cssh` on the server to change your default shell.

Comment: `chsh` :) doesn't work since system admin has blocked it for non-root users. All problems now solved, just need to modify `~/.tcshrc` and when defining aliases use the correct syntax for tcsh/csh. Many thanks

Comment: Damn, same typo both times... It just means CHange SHell and I still get it wrong :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things to consider here:

1. It sounds like you are not using `bash` on the remote server so your `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` will not be read.
2. `ssh` starts a login shell on the remote server so even if you *were* running `bash`, `.bashrc` would not be read. That file is only read by interactive, non-login shells.

Many login shells, however, read `~/.profile`. I can't be sure since you have not mentioned which shell you are using but chances are that if you add this line to your `~/.profile` file (on the remote server) you'll get your variable set:

```
PYTHONPATH="place/stuff/this_goes_on_forever"
```

---

Since you are running `tcsh`, the startup files are different. From `man tcsh`:

```
   A login shell begins  by  executing  commands  from  the  system  files
   /etc/csh.cshrc  and  /etc/csh.login.   It  then  executes commands from
   files in  the  user's  home  directory:  first  ~/.tcshrc  (+)  or,  if
   ~/.tcshrc  is not found, ~/.cshrc, then ~/.history (or the value of the
   histfile shell variable), then ~/.login, and finally ~/.cshdirs (or the
   value  of  the  dirsfile  shell  variable)  (+).   The  shell  may read
   /etc/csh.login before instead of  after  /etc/csh.cshrc,  and  ~/.login
   before  instead  of  after  ~/.tcshrc or ~/.cshrc and ~/.history, if so
   compiled; see the version shell variable. (+)
```

So, you should add your `setenv` command to `~/.tcshrc` on the remote server.

Finally, since it sounds like you are more used to `bash`, why don't you change the shell you use on the remote server? Just log in to the server and then run

```
chsh
```

Give it `/bin/bash` as your default shell and all these problems go away. You will then be able to set variables and aliases as you would expect, by editing `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile` on the remote server.

Comment: Hi, `echo $0` when logged on to the server returns `-tcsh`. Also `man csh` returns the `csh` documentation so I think that must be what the server runs. I have created `~/.cshrc` and added the code to that, and it works! Thank you :D 

As side note: I tried running cssh and it returned `command not found`.

Comment: @Marchy my bad, that should be `chsh` not `cssh`.

Comment: Thanks :) `chsh` has been disabled for non-root users by system admin, but I'm quite happy learning the ways of a new shell

Comment: This also solves my problem with aliases since the syntax is different in csh/tcsh when using `alias`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using csh on the server, add your code to the csh start up there. csh has a slightly different syntax than bash to set aliases, do a man csh on your server for information.

Comment: It IS running csh, I've now added the code to `~/.cshrc`. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Test which shell you are using by running:

```
echo $SHELL
```

If it is bash, and it is not automatically reading ~/.bashrc, you may need to create a ~/.bash_profile file.

```
$ cat .bash_profile 
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
fi
```

Regarding this:

> I tried ~./.bash_profile after, didn't work.

If you meant that you were trying to source the profile file, that syntax is wrong.  To source an environment file, run this:

```
. ~/.bash_profile
```

Comment: `echo $SHELL` does not print the shell you are currently using. It prints the default shell which is not necessarily the same. Try running a different shell and `echo $SHELL`.

Comment: Hi, that was a typo as regards `~/.bash.profile` :S thanks though :) [now edited the original question]